# Ethical Hacking Certification (CEH v9) From A Web Developer's Perspective

Tags: network, penetration-test, physical, software

I just finished a week of training for the CEH v9 certification. I have two questions:

1. What are some strategies I can take for studying for the CEH v9 certification coming at the test as a web developer having minimal experience with hardware?
2. It seems to me that taking these CEH courses prepared me to do penetration testing as a script kiddie - I may know how to use some tools that a professional made, but I'm not an expert in what is really going on. Is that the goal of becoming CEH certified? Being a script kiddie? I understand that ultimately I need to know the techniques people use to infiltrate a system, but I have a problem calling myself an "expert" when I don't understand what the tools are doing and in most cases, how to even interpret the results.

Comment: I personally don't have any experience with CEH v9 and please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but is the second part of your question basically: "Why did a one week course not turn me into a 'super hacker'?"

Comment: The first part of the question is off-topic here: study strategies for a particular exam is a better fit on a study site for that exam. The second part assumes that the goal of the course is to teach you how to be a penetration tester, and it is not. The goal is to teach you the tools.

Comment: I did CEHv7 many years back. It's all about tools. You get to know what things are possible to begin with. Later you can build expertise gradually at your own with plenty of resources. But you surely need to understand the fundamentals to pass the certification.